# Python leaks memory if I read a tuple instead of single value

Tags: python, rocksdb

I'm querying whether a key exists in a RocksDB database using Python. The API (see bottom) implies it returns a two-element tuple. So I receive both tuple elements:

```
def contains_key(database: rocksdb, key: int) -> bool:
    found, data = database.key_may_exist(key)
    return found
```

and I am using it like this:

```
if not contains_key(database, key):
```

However, this causes a memory leak.

To prove this, if I change the code to:

```
def contains_key(database: rocksdb, key: int) -> bool:
    return database.key_may_exist(key)
```

there is no leak (but it's obviously not correct).

How do I get the first version to work without a memory leak?

[image]

Comment: Your first function isn't even valid Python; assignments are statements, and can't be part of an expression (which is what `return` expects).

Comment: Can you clarify how you notice the memory leak?

Comment: If you only want to return the first part of the tuple, use `return database.key_may_exist(key)[0]`.

Comment: What about the thing that calls this function? In the second case, `contains_key` returns a 2 valued tuple which is always `True`. Since the thing that calls `contains_key` is expecting a bool, it may be doing simple truth value testing. It would think that `(False, None)` (no key) is really `True` (has key) and do something bad and memory eating from there.

Comment: Your updated code does not have a memory leak, or if it does, the problem is with the library you are using, not your code.

Comment: @chepner - most likely its the thing calling this function which expects a boolean.

Comment: Apologies all, i had to manually retype the code from the remote machine. I've corrected it

Comment: I still don't see how any of what you show would relate to a memory leak. Your code merely unpacks a tuple and tests a boolean – millions of programs use that every day. *How* do you notice there is a memory leak, and *why* do you assume these lines are the reason? Note that your alternative code would always result in a truthy value, and thus skip the body of the ``if`` – meaning that a cause for an observed memory like would be in the body, not the test.

Comment: In your second case, a tuple is returned that is always True. The suite in `if not contains_key(database, key):` never runs. Look in that `if` for the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code

```
def contains_key(database: rocksdb, key: int) -> bool:
    found, data = database.key_may_exist(key)
    return found
```

does not contain a memory leak.

`found` and `data` are two names in the local scope, and both refer to values that exist in a single area of memory. When the function returns, `found` and `data` go out of scope. What `found` referred to can be referred to by the caller (`x = contains_key(db, 3)`), but `data` is ignored. Since no other reference to that object exists, Python (as a garbage-collecting language) reclaims whatever resources were devoted to `data` automatically.

For that matter, the `key_may_exist` method returns a tuple that you never safe a reference to. It is immediately unpacked, with `found` and `data` referring to whatever that tuple referred to. The tuple itself is garbage-collected, but the references to its contents remain.

Comment: I've just updated and added a line to show how I am using my function. It's simply within an IF statement.

Comment: Doesn't matter: there is *no* leak in this code. `not` can use the return value without saving a reference to the object, just as the `if` statement can use the result of the `not` expression to make a decision. Any value that doesn't have an explicit reference saved is simply reclaimed by Python after the current expression or statement is done with it.

Comment: Python simply *does not have* any notion of manual memory management. Even `del` does not actually delete an object; it deletes a *name* from the current scope, which has the side effect of decrementing the reference count of the object referred to by the name. *If* the reference count becomes 0 as a result, the runtime reclaims the objects. Memory leaks are a bug in the interpreter, not your code. (As an exception, Python extensions written in C can introduce memory leaks, but that's because you are extending the *interpreter*, not writing Python code.)

Comment: rocksdb  (a C++ library) could be growing in the background. OP has a bug that is masked by the ill-advised change to  `contains_key`. All OP did was mask one bug with another. By returning a 2-tuple, `if not contains_key(database, key):` doesn't run. The code always thinks that the key exists. Its the code that deals with a new key that is buggy.

Comment: Without knowing the details of the bug, it's impossible to answer. If the changed code doesn't have a leak, it's because of an interaction *specific* to the bug itself, not a general Python technique.